# executeQuery() in JDBC is returning incorrect rows

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

The following query is returning one extra row than when the query is run in database:

```
select distinct employeeId as facilityId,0 as numberOfRequests 
from If_User 
where role='Facility Staff' 
and employeeId not in (select distinct facilityId 
                       from IF_Request 
                       where requestStatus='C' 
                         and allocationTime like '09-12-16%');
```

This is returned in JDBC:

```
FacilityID numberOfRequests

8585            0
7427            0
2545            0
```

Where the actual data in SQLDeveloper is:

```
FacilityID numberOfRequests
8585            0
7427            0
```

[image: IF_Request Table]

[image: IF_User Table]

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `distinct` in the sub-query is useless

Comment: Thanks it worked!

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by relying on the implicit data type conversion that is triggered by using `LIKE` on a `DATE` column. `LIKE` is **only** for character values. The `LIKE` forces Oracle to convert the date value to a string. When run from SQL Developer other rules apply for the evil implicit data type conversion then when you run this through your application.

Use proper date literal instead e.g.

```
where trunc(allocationtime) = date '2016-12-09'
```

If that needs to be a parameter from within Java, use a `PreparedStatement` and pass an instance of `java.sql.Timestamp` using `setTimestamp()` do not pass String values for DATE or TIMESTAMP parameters.

Oracle's DATE **always** contains a time part and and therefor you have to use `trunc()` on the column value to normalize that to `00:00:00`

#### Never use `LIKE` on a `DATE`, `TIMESTAMP` or `NUMBER` column!